# cannot pass variable to the next page via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm making a chat system between users and operator,which contain of chatbox written by html and posechat.php to bring the data from database to the chatbox via jquery.

```
<div id="chatbox"></div>

    <form>
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

jquery:

```
 $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
            var clientid = $("#uid").val();
            $.post("includes/postchat.php", {text: clientmsg,uid: clientid});
            $.post("includes/posechat.php", {text: clientmsg,uid: clientid});
            $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        });
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#chatbox').load('includes/posechat.php');
        }, 1000);
    });
```

I put an username in the tail of chatbox to identify the the user ( ex: chatsystem.html?user=Adam).I want to fetch that data($uid) to the posechat.php for sql statement to display the right output in the chatbox but it doesnt seem to work, got an error: Undefined index 
Here's the posechat.php:

```
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['u_uid'];

include('dbh-inc.php');
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
echo $uid;
```

Comment: is `$_SESSION['u_uid']` defined ?

Comment: Yes, it might be a little confuse the way i named the variables, $_SESSION is defined in the current session when I log in. $uid is the information from the chatbox.html

Comment: are you looking to fill #chatbox with the chats from the database? i can't see any code that updates the #chatbox though. you've got 2 ajax calls in your JS click handler, but either of them doesn't update the #chatbox, what do you expect to happen when you click #submitmsg button?

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: same page(posechat) is used to write & read messages so use an if condition to check if uid is set if it is then it is write else read that why on reading it says undefined index

Comment: it work with the one to write the text to database but not the one that bring the data out of database